# Can't create mysql table with foreign key

Tags: mysql

I am getting errno 150 when I try to create the following two tables.

```
 CREATE TABLE `mydatabase`.`userstatus`( 
   `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
   `description` VARCHAR(255) , 
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 );



CREATE TABLE `mydatabase`.users( 
   `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   `email` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL , 
   `username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown' , 
   `userstatusid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 2 , 
   `datemodified` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `datecreated` DATETIME DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE (username),
   UNIQUE (email),
   INDEX userstatusid_index (userstatusid),
   CONSTRAINT fk_users_userstatus FOREIGN KEY (userstatusid) REFERENCES userstatus(id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE

 )  ENGINE=INNODB  ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT ;
```

What's causing the error and how do I fix it?

Comment: did u try removing "DEFAULT 2" from userstatusid definition?

Comment: Yes, I've tried removing the default 2 from userstatusid. I have also tried adding ENGINE=INNODB to the first table userstatus.

Answer (score 2):

I put on delete set null but the column has been defined as not null. I was focusing too much attention to the types which usually causes the errno 150.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try set a Unique key on userstatusid.
Sometimes that may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `SHOW INNODB STATUS` which will show the last InnoDB error (e.g. foreign key constraint definition problems).

(Otherwise you have to just guess based on the error number and limited information which the error from the statement provides, which isn't ideal.)

Comment: I think you mean `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

Comment: Thank you, this command has changed since I wrote the answer. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-innodb-status.html